# Pesquisa com Checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Estou tentando criar um sistema de pesquisa na minha aplicação onde o usuário pode pesquisar as publicações do site de acordo com o gênero. Eu consigo listar os generos cadastrados com  checkbox, mas estou perdido para fazer a query de busca a partir daí.

Eu tenho as seguintes tabelas:

```
Publicacao
Genero
PublicacaoGenero(IdPublicacao e IdGenero)
```

Edit:

```
public ActionResult Publicacoes(PesquisaPublicacoesViewModel viewModel = null)
        {
            if (viewModel == null)
            {
                PesquisaPublicacoesViewModel p = new PesquisaPublicacoesViewModel();
                p.TodosOsGeneros = db.Generos.ToList();
                p.PublicacoesSelecionadas = db.Publicacao.Where(x => x.Titulo.StartsWith(p.Titulo) && x.Aprovado).ToList();
                return View(p);

            }

            viewModel.TodosOsGeneros = db.Generos.ToList();


            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewModel.Titulo))
            {
                viewModel.PublicacoesSelecionadas = db.Publicacao.Where(p => p.Aprovado).ToList();

            }
            else
            {
                viewModel.PublicacoesSelecionadas = db.Publicacao.Where(p => p.Titulo.StartsWith(viewModel.Titulo) && p.Aprovado).ToList();

            }

            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

View:

```
 @model AllFiction.ViewModels.PesquisaPublicacoesViewModel

@using(Html.BeginForm("Publicacoes","Publicacoes",FormMethod.Get))
{

@Html.TextBox("Titulo", null, new {id="txtTitulo" })


@Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.IdGenerosSelecionados,
                        model => model.TodosOsGeneros,
                        genero => genero.IdGenero,
                        genero => genero.Genero,
                        model => model.GenerosSelecionados)

}

@foreach (var p in Model.PublicacoesSelecionadas)
{
    @p.Usuario1.NomeCompleto
    @p.Titulo
}
```

Tentei adicionar o foreach para poder listar as publicações, o que funciona. Porém, ele ignora as opções selecionadas na checkbox, e exibe todas as publicações(se o usuario não digitar nada) ou as publicações que possuem os caracteres digitados na caixa de texto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para isso, você precisará usar o pacote NuGet **MvcCheckBoxList**:

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcCheckBoxList/

Antes monte um `ViewModel` com algumas coisas:

```
public class PesquisaPublicacoesViewModel
{
    // Coloque aqui todos os parâmetros que você usa pra fazer a pesquisa
    public string Titulo { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Publicacao> PublicacoesSelecionadas { get; set; }

    public string[] IdsDosGenerosSelecionados { get; set; }
    public IList<Genero> TodosOsGeneros;
    public IList<Genero> GenerosSelecionados;
}
```

Depois coloque na sua *View*:

```
@model SeuProjeto.ViewModels.PesquisaPublicacoesViewModel

@Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.IdsDosGenerosSelecionados,
                        model => model.TodosOsGeneros,
                        genero => genero.GeneroId,
                        genero => genero.Nome,
                        model => model.GenerosSelecionados)
```

Portanto, esse *Controller* agora fica assim:

```
public ActionResult Publicacoes(PesquisaPublicacoesViewModel viewModel = null)
{
    if (viewModel == null) {
        // Inicie o ViewModel com alguns dados padrão.
    }

    viewModel.TodosOsGeneros = db.Generos.ToList();
    // Essa linha abaixo é facultativa. Coloque apenas se quiser que os gêneros já venham preenchidos.
    viewModel.GenerosSelecionados = db.Generos.Where(...);

    List<Publicacao> pub;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pesquisa))
    {
        viewModel.PublicacoesSelecionadas = db.Publicacao.Where(p => p.Aprovado).ToList();

    }
    else
    {
        viewModel.PublicacoesSelecionadas = db.Publicacao.Where(p => p.Titulo.StartsWith(viewModel.Titulo) && p.Aprovado).ToList();

    }

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: Só me explique duas coias, por favor. Não entendi bem a linha "// Inicie o ViewModel com alguns dados padrão." Seria instanciar a classe PesquisaPublicacoesViewModel? E o que são exatamente ViewModels?

Comment: Sim, é preciso instanciar a classe caso ela venha nula na requisição. *ViewModels* são *Models* que não são persistidos em banco. São perfeitos pra montar telas e colocar lá a informação que você quiser.

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Me tire mais uma duvida, por favor. O que eu devo adicionar na view para poder exibir as publicações? Tentei utilizar um foreach, mas não deu muito certo, ele acaba exibindo todas as publicações independente do genero escolhido... Se precisar eu abro outra pergunta.

Comment: @RyanSantos Melhor abrir outra, até pra eu entender como está seu código agora.

Comment: Resolvi editar, pois não fiz grandes alterações no código. Se você puder dar uma olhada agora.

Comment: Tenho quase certeza que não está correto... Não sei se vou conseguir explicar direito. Mas acho que eu deveria fazer um if para poder comparar quais generos o usuario marcou na checkbox e quais publicações se encaixam com esses valores...

Comment: @RyanSantos Não há comparações com gêneros no seu `Where()`. Faça outra pergunta que a explicação é um pouco comprida.

Comment: Aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40678/filtrar-pesquisa-com-valores-da-checkbox