# Filtrar pesquisa com valores da Checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Por exemplo, o Usuario digitou o titulo de uma publicação, e marcou os generos Ação e Aventura, ou o usuario não digitou titulo nenhum, mas deseja ver todas as publicações que se enquadram nesses gêneros. Como eu posso fazer essa query de busca?

Minhas tabelas:

```
Publicacao
Generos
PublicacaoGenero(IdPublicacao e IdGenero)
```

Action:

```
public ActionResult Publicacoes(PesquisaPublicacoesViewModel viewModel = null)
        {
            if (viewModel == null)
            {
                PesquisaPublicacoesViewModel p = new PesquisaPublicacoesViewModel();
                p.TodosOsGeneros = db.Generos.ToList();
                p.PublicacoesSelecionadas = db.Publicacao.Where(x => x.Titulo.StartsWith(p.Titulo) && x.Aprovado).ToList();
                return View(p);

            }

            viewModel.TodosOsGeneros = db.Generos.ToList();


            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewModel.Titulo))
            {
                viewModel.PublicacoesSelecionadas = db.Publicacao.Where(p => p.Aprovado).ToList();

            }
            else
            {
                viewModel.PublicacoesSelecionadas = db.Publicacao.Where(p => p.Titulo.StartsWith(viewModel.Titulo) && p.Aprovado).ToList();

            }

            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

View:

```
@model AllFiction.ViewModels.PesquisaPublicacoesViewModel

@using(Html.BeginForm("Publicacoes","Publicacoes",FormMethod.Get))
{

@Html.TextBox("Titulo", null, new {id="txtTitulo" })


@Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.IdGenerosSelecionados,
                        model => model.TodosOsGeneros,
                        genero => genero.IdGenero,
                        genero => genero.Genero,
                        model => model.GenerosSelecionados)

}

@foreach (var p in Model.PublicacoesSelecionadas)
{
    @p.Usuario1.NomeCompleto
    @p.Titulo
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class PesquisaPublicacoesViewModel
    {

        public string Titulo { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Publicacao> PublicacoesSelecionadas { get; set; }

        public string[] IdGenerosSelecionados { get; set; }
        public IList<Generos> TodosOsGeneros;
        public IList<Generos> GenerosSelecionados;

    }
```

Comment: Faltou você colocar o código da ViewModel.

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40615/pesquisa-com-checkbox/40624

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Editado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No momento em que há o envio da *ViewModel* para o *Controller*, há duas maneiras de obter as Ids dos gêneros selecionados:

- Através da property `IdGenerosSelecionados`;
- Através da coleção `GenerosSelecionados`.

Para obter os Ids de `GenerosSelecionados`, é possível usar algo assim:

```
var ids = viewModel.GenerosSelecionados.Select(g => g.GeneroId).ToList();
```

Usando um ou outro, a consulta ficaria assim:

```
viewModel.PublicacoesSelecionadas = db.Publicacao.Where(p => p.Aprovado && viewModel.IdGenerosSelecionados.Contains(p.PublicacaoGenero.GeneroId)).ToList();
```

Ou ainda:

```
viewModel.PublicacoesSelecionadas = db.Publicacao.Where(p => p.Aprovado && ids.Contains(p.PublicacaoGenero.GeneroId)).ToList();
```

Cabe a você o jeito que preferir usar. Não esqueça de carregar `PublicacaoGenero` utilizando `Include()`.

Ah, outra coisa: você pode reescrever seu Controller assim:

```
    public ActionResult Publicacoes(PesquisaPublicacoesViewModel viewModel = null)
    {
        if (viewModel == null)
        {
            PesquisaPublicacoesViewModel p = new PesquisaPublicacoesViewModel();
            p.TodosOsGeneros = db.Generos.ToList();
            p.PublicacoesSelecionadas = db.Publicacao.Where(x => x.Titulo.StartsWith(p.Titulo) && x.Aprovado).ToList();
            return View(p);
        }

        viewModel.TodosOsGeneros = db.Generos.ToList();
        viewModel.PublicacoesSelecionadas = db.Publicacao.Include(p => p.PublicacaoGenero).Where(p => p.Aprovado).ToList();

        if (viewModel.GenerosSelecionados != null && viewModel.GenerosSelecionados.Any()) {
            var ids = viewModel.GenerosSelecionados.Select(g => g.GeneroId).ToList();
            viewModel.PublicacoesSelecionadas = db.Publicacao.Where(p => viewModel.IdGenerosSelecionados.Contains(p.PublicacaoGenero.GeneroId)).ToList();
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewModel.Titulo))
        {
            viewModel.PublicacoesSelecionadas = viewModel.PublicacoesSelecionadas.Where(p => p.Titulo.StartsWith(viewModel.Titulo)).ToList();
        }

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

PS: Eu não testei este código. Alguma variação pode ocorrer.

Comment: O unico problema é que eu não guardo o Id do genero na table Publicacao ai essa parte (p.GeneroId) da erro. Você acha que o mais correto, para esse caso, seria associar diretamente a tabela publicacão com a tabela Genero? (eliminando a tabela PublicacaoGenero)

Comment: Vou mudar a resposta.

Comment: Se for muito trabalhoso, eu posso alterar o banco de dados sem problema...

Comment: Não precisa. Já atualizei. Veja como ficou.

Comment: Agora Funcionou. Obrigado pela ajuda, e pela paciência.